# Publishing ASP.NET MVC/AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application with an AngularJS front-end and it's working great when running from visual studio/iis express, but not so great when I try to publish it so it's accessible to other users (e.g. navigating to http://server/application in a browser). I have IIS configured on server so that http://server/application points to an "application" folder that is structured as:

```
application
    app
        areas
        foundation
        main
            layout
                layout.html
    bin
    Content
    fonts
    Scripts
    Templates
    Views
        Shared
            _Layout.cshtml
            Index.cshtml
    Logs
    Global.asax
    web.config
```

The initial page, Index.cshtml (under Views/Shared/), gets loaded but includes this:

```
<div ng-include="'app/main/layout/layout.html'"></div>
```

which returns a 500.24 - Internal Server Error.

If I change the ng-include to:

```
<div ng-include="'application/app/main/layout/layout.html'"></div>
```

then the published application works but running it from visual studio/iis express returns a 404.0 - Not Found response when trying to load that layout.html file, I'm assuming because there's no parent "application" folder when it's running using iisexpress.

I did manage to get the published application working at one point by copying the contents of the published application folder to server's C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder but that doesn't seem like a proper solution, so what's the best way to inform Angular to look in the correct location for this ng-include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is adding an application path variable in my web.config file and prefixing all my ng-include or other urls with the application path, so they looked like

```
<div ng-include="'application/app/main/layout/layout.html'"></div>
```

and then updating my project Web properties to the following:
[image]

so that whether I publish it or run it through Visual Studio, it's running under the 'application' folder and looking for the html files in the appropriate location.